# import com.mongodb.MongoClient isn't recognize by intellij IDEA 2018.1.6

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a project in which I will be able to access mongo db through my controller and get forms from the user.

In my pom file I have declared to mongodb-driver, but when I try to `import com.mongodb.MongoClient I get an error - **cannot resolve symbol mongodb**.

I am trying to use the mongodb java driver with spring boot, since I have studied how to use in the M101J course.

The pom -here's the file -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>form-java-spring-freemarker</artifactId>
    <name>form-java-spring-freemarker</name>
    <description>form-java-spring-freemarker</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The other file - User.java -

```
    package com.hellokoding.springboot;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

The file tree -

[image: file tree]

Comment: Argh legacy of originally being org! Shows how much I bother to look at package names. Are you possitive you have updated all project dependencies? Typically this sort of thing generally means that maven has not pulled down the changes made in the pom as yet. IntelliiJ probably should prompt you to turn on automatic updating, but it's possible you missed the message. You can enable auto updates from the menu.

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:resolve` then try again.

Comment: @EugenCovaci strange. Did both, still no luck. Intellij even told me about "build success"

Comment: Ok! I have downgraded the mongodb driver version to 3.6.4 and it worked. Thanks both of you!

Comment: Assaf, actually, this is very interesting error. I have `java: cannot access com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings class file for com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings not found issue` because of `spring-boot-starter-parent` dependency. If I delete it then I haven't any warnings with mongo java driver newer versions. So I think it happens due to conflict between library spring boot starter and mongo newer drivers 3.7+ versions. Or use older like 3.4/3.6 as you did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expected, I had also the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043742/cannot-access-com-mongodb-mongoclientsettings-mongodb-java-driver-3-7) because of conflict between newer version of mongodb driver 3.7+ and spring boot starter dependency, as I mentioned in comments. And solved it by adding instead of

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

newer version like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

So, I highly recommend to use last versions of drivers and spring boot starter dependencies. And it should save you from such errors, I'm sure.

But also you can avoid it using older versions of mongodb java drivers, as you did it.