# Cannot access com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings - MongoDB Java driver 3.7+

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm following the [guide](https://www.opencodez.com/java/use-mongodb-atlas-with-spring-boot.htm) using MongoDB Java driver 3.7+ versions with Spring boot starter as dependency. And I get the error:

```
java: cannot access com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings class file for 
com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings not found
```

My POM file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bot</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework.data.version>1.11.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.data.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.data.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>project.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My class-entity is like:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@Document(collection = "messages")
public class Messages {

    @Id
    private Integer user_id;
    private String message;

    public Messages(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
```

Repository interface for pagination:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface Repository  extends MongoRepository<Messages, String> {
    Page<Messages> findByMessages(String message, Pageable pageable);
}
```

After analyzing and testing, I understand this error appears because of conflict between of dependencies `spring boot starter` and newer versions of `mongodb java driver 3.7+` :

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

If I delete this `parent` dependency then everything is good with MongoDB Java driver. But I need it using annotations for interface and class.

I tried to solve this error writting explicitly `Mongoclient`:

```
com.mongodb.client.MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://admin:password@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
```

Instead of:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://admin:password@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
```

But it doesn't help me to avoid the issue.

Also I checked via command: `mvn dependency:resolve` how it resolves all the project dependencies from the repository, I get:

```
Build success.
```

Can someone tell me, please, how to solve this problem correctly using newer MongoDB Java drivers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding newer version spring boot starter in POM file:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

So, I highly recommend to use last versions of drivers and spring boot starter dependencies. And it should save you from such errors.

But also you can avoid it using older versions of mongodb java drivers.